# How can I sort my input array if it is defined as const?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, constants

I am trying to sort my input array `pAddrSourceArray` in and ascending way, but the input array is defined as `const` as it is shown in below header, that cannot be changed since it is imposed.

So far I have the idea of how to sort the array, however I am struggling to overcome the fact that the input array is defined as constant. I cannot (or I don't know) how to create an auxiliary array with the content of the input one, so that I can sort this auxiliary one and then assign to the output array `pAddrResultArray`

Any hints of how to solve this?

```
void sortArray(uint32_t samplesCount, const int16_t *pAddrSourceArray, int16_t *pAddrResultArray)
{
    int16_t *pInputArray = pAddrSourceArray; // This is wrong, I know it should be const  int16_t *pInputArray = pAddrSourceArray;

    int16_t min_idx;

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
    for (uint32_t indxUnsort = 0; indxUnsort < samplesCount - 1; indxUnsort++ )
    {

        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
        min_idx = indxUnsort;
        for (uint32_t k = indxUnsort + 1; k < samplesCount; k++)
        {
            if (pInputArray[k] < pInputArray[min_idx])
            {
                min_idx = k;
            }
        }

        // Store actual local min value
        int16_t localMin = pInputArray[min_idx];
        // Update new min at current indxUsort position
        pInputArray[min_idx] = pInputArray[indxUnsort];
        // Append the new local min found
        pInputArray[indxUnsort] = localMin;
    }

    // Assign sorted array to output array
    pAddrResultArray = pInputArray;
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to sort it in-place. You have `pAddrResultArray` for the result. And it is to be provided by the caller.

Comment: Are you allowed to allocate a new array with `malloc`? `samplesCount` is the number of elements in the input array?

Comment: @zois Looking at the function signature, the output buffer is to be allocated by the caller.

Comment: @zois I cannot use malloc, it is not allowed neither

Comment: @EugeneSh. has given you the crux of the solution.  I want to try to clear up another misunderstanding I see from your code.  Your last line `pAddrResultArray = pInputArray;` doesn't do anything meaningful.  It assigns the value of the local pointer, but as soon as your function returns, that identifier goes out of scope.  Remember than in C everything is pass by value.

Comment: @MFisherKDX does that mean that I cannot solve it as it is?

Comment: @ndarkness: Is my assumption correct that you are attempting to use a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) algorithm? If that is the case, then you don't need an "auxiliary array", you can write the sort results directly to the output array.

Comment: @andreaswenzel, indeed i am trying to do so. How could I do it then? Replacing all usage of the auxiliar array by the output one?

Comment: @ndarkness: `"How could I do it then? Replacing all usage of the auxiliar array by the output one?"` In your posted code, you do not have an auxiliary array. Therefore, your question whether you should replace its use with the output array does not make sense. What you should do is never write to the input array (which is pointed to by `pAddrSourceArray` and `pInputArray`), but instead write to the output array (which is pointed to by `pAddrResultArray`).

Comment: @ndarkness: I suggest that you delete the line `int16_t* pInputArray = pAddrSourceArray;`, as this line is not helpful. You should only reference the input array through `pAddrSourceArray` and the output array through `pAddrResultArray`.

Comment: @andreaswenzel I will delete that line, but I would like to understand, how can I use the output array if it doesn't contain my initial array/valued? I mean the algorithm is sorting the data of the input array by looking for its minimum and rearranging the input array  elements from lower value to higher one

Comment: @ndarkness: Ah, yes, you are right that the standard selection sort algorithm will not work if you are not sorting the array in-place. Therefore, if you want to use the standard selection sort algorithm, you will first have to copy the entire input array into the output array and then do an in-place sort there. Were you told to use a specific sort algorithm or are you allowed to sort it using any algorithm you want?

Comment: @ndarkness: Was is part of your assignment to sort the array contents in an "auxiliary array" and then only write the results into the output array? In that case, if you are not allowed to use `malloc`, you will have to declare a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and then sort it there.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel no I wasn't told to use any sorting algorithm in concrete, I chose that one since I thought that it would be the easier, but then I stumbled with the `const` input array.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel nope, the assignment didn't specify neither the usage an auxiliary array for sorting purposes, I came up with it too. I think that copying the input array into the output can do the trick. But if I I use the variable length array technique otherwise I will end up in the same problem again, copying a `const` variable into a not one...

Comment: @ndarkness: I would only recommend using a variable-length array if your assignment specifically told you that you must use an auxiliary array and are not allowed to use `malloc`. However, since you state that your assignment does not require you to use an auxiliary array, I do not recommend using variable-length arrays. Instead, I recommend that you copy the entire input array to the output array and then do all the sorting there.

Comment: @ndarkness: There is nothing wrong with copying a `const` variable into a non-`const` variable. Only the reverse is a problem, or, in your case, swapping a `const` variable with another `const` variable, as that involves writing to a `const` variable. In other words, you are allowed to swap array elements in the output array, but not in the input array.

Comment: I would like to point out that the assignment does not make much sense to me. If the caller of the function `sortArray` is responsible for providing the output buffer, it might as well also handle the copying of the array, so that it only has to pass the copied array to `sortArray`. In my opinion, this would make more sense than passing two arrays to `sortArray` and making that function handle the copying. Therefore, I do not consider the program structure specified by the assignment to be meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to sort the source array in place, but you can simply copy it to the destination array and sort that one in place with a method of your choice:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp_int16_t(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const int16_t *s1 = p1;
    const int16_t *s2 = p2;
    return (*s1 > *s2) - (*s1 < *s2);
}

void sortArray(uint32_t samplesCount, const int16_t *pAddrSourceArray, int16_t *pAddrResultArray) {
    memmove(pAddrResultArray, pAddrSourceArray, samplesCount * sizeof(*pAddrResultArray));
    qsort(pAddrResultArray, samplesCount, sizeof(*pAddrResultArray), cmp_int16_t);
}
```

Comment: I have noticed that in your solution you use `memmove()` but this function relies on `memcopy()`, in case I don't have `memcopy`, I should make use of the @AndreasWenzel idea of copying the entire input array to the output array and then do all the sorting there, correct?

Comment: @ndarkness: by `memcopy`, I assume you mean `memcpy`, which should not be used in this case because the source and destination areas could overlap. `memmove` (and `memcpy`) is a standard library function declared in `<string.h>`. If you do not have it or are not allowed to used it, you can write a simple copy loop: `for (uint32_t i = 0; i < samplesCount; i++) {  pAddrResultArray [i] = pAddrSourceArray [i]; }`. Sorting the array into the destination with a generic algorithm might produce incorrect results if the same array is passed as source and destination for `sortArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. It takes each input value in turn from the input array, and inserts it into the output array at the position of the first element of the output array that is greater than the input array if any, otherwise at the end of output array, shuffling the remaining elements of the output array up by one. This ensures that output array filled so far is always in ascending order.

Since the output array contents so far are already sorted in ascending order, the position to insert the input value can be determined using a binary search.

The overall average time complexity of O(N^2) is dominated by the insertion of elements into the output array, although the binary search to find the insertion position so far helps a bit, being O(log n) compared to O(n) for a linear search.

```
void sortArray(uint32_t samplesCount, const int16_t* pAddrSourceArray, int16_t* pAddrResultArray)
{
    uint32_t s;

    for (s = 0; s < samplesCount; s++)
    {
        /* Get next value from input. */
        int16_t xs = pAddrSourceArray[s];
        uint32_t a, b;

        /* Find position where next value belongs in the output so far by a binary search. */
        a = 0;
        b = s;
        while (a < b)
        {
            uint32_t m = (a + b) / 2;

            if (xs < pAddrResultArray[m])
            {
                b = m;
            }
            else
            {
                a = m + 1;
            }
        }
        /* Insert value at position in output array, shuffling up remaining elements. */
        while (a < s)
        {
            int16_t xa = pAddrResultArray[a];

            pAddrResultArray[a] = xs;
            xs = xa;
            a++;
        }
        pAddrResultArray[a] = xs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know it should be `const`, then declare it as:

```
const int16_t *pInputArray
```

but when you initialized a non-const pointer with a `const int16_t *` you should receive at least a warning from the compiler (telling something similar to `initializer discards 'const' qualifier`).

As in

```
void f(const int *a)
{
        int *b = a;
}
```

which on compiling gives:

```
pru58405.c:4:7: warning: initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'const int *' discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
        int *b = a;
             ^   ~
1 warning generated.
```

The `const`ness of the objects you manage in your programs depend strongly on the types you use for the variables.  Once you declare it non`const`, you can access it and modify without problem (except if it is located in a true read only segment, in which case, you'll probably get an exception if you try to modify the values)

As you posted an incomplete, non verifiable example (read the page entitled [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) it is impossible to go further in what we can do for you.  My apologies for that.